# What's the best way to rename a column referenced in a computed column?

Tags: sql-server-2005, calculated-columns

I'm trying to rename a column using `sp_rename` but it's referenced in a computed column. I'm getting the following error:

> 'Table.Column' cannot be renamed because the object participates in enforced dependencies.

As far as I can tell the (persisted) computed column is the only place this is referenced. I guess I can drop and recreate the computed column since I won't technically be losing any data, but I wondered if there was a cleaner way?

Thanks

Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the SSMS runs into exactly the same error, I'm thinking there's not a better way than dropping and recreating the computed column.

Comment: Which turns into a bit of a mess of dropping constraints and relationships and then reinstating them. Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it.

First you should open the table designer than change the computed column name from here
right click on it and then click on  generate change table script. copy the script and execute it.

it will rename the column without losing data

vimal lohani
DBA | MCP(70-461)